# What's the meaning of `noisy` in `noisy scanner`?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

When I watching a [video time 2:56](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MTZdN9TEO4&list=PLBf0hzazHTGOEuhPQSnq-Ej8jRyXxfYvl&index=4)

> that is a very very very noisy scanner...

What's the meaning of `noisy` there? We know noisy is a adjective word for voice, but what's the meaning of it in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where you got the idea that "noisy" only applies to voices. A [good dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/noisy) would give you an answer.

Noisy describes anything "making or given to making a lot of noise" and also usually implies that the noise is *excessive*.

A "noisy scanner" would be a scanner that makes more noise than is either wanted or expected from a scanner.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have time to watch and listen to the whole video, but in technical contexts noise does not only refer to sounds but also to other disturbances in signals (see "signal-to-noise ratio" etc.).
If for example nmap outputs a lot of stuff that is not of interest at the moment you could describe this output as noise.

Answer (score 0):

Having watched the video, it is making an analogy of network traffic with real sound.

Imagine a very very noisy person banging on all the doors and windows of all the houses in a street trying to see if any are open - That's how nmap appears to a detection system.

The firewalls will know you are doing it.